# Read specific raster files and create a mean raster in R

Tags: r, design-patterns, raster, qgis

I am desesperate, because my problem seems very simple, but I cannot find out how to manage it.

**Aim:**

1. I would like to read 1 to 4 raster files from a folder. The names of the one that I need are listed in a list as character.
2. After having opened the files, I would like to create a new raster corresponding to the mean of the files.

I can manage it on QGIS, but I need to automatize hte process, as I have a lot of individuals!

1) It should work with  `list.files(pattern = )`  but as the names are in a list, I do not know how to do.

Ex: for the first individual, I have to read 2 files named `2018-12-27_sic.tif` and `2018-12-27_sic_con.tif`

I tried to read with     `readGDAL`    ,     `open.GDAL`    it didn't work

thanks a lot for your valuable help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `stack` and `calc` functions from the `raster` package.  The function `stack` creates a stack of rasters, all with the same resolution and extent, and makes it easy to do operations like take the mean of every cell. So:

```
library(raster)

fs <- list.files(pattern='tif$')

rasterstack <- stack(fs)

rastermean <- calc(rasterstack, fun=mean)
```

Note, if your rasters are not the same resolution, you will have to use the `resample` function, and if they are not the same extent, you will have to use `crop`.  Typing in `?resample` and `?crop` in RStudio will show you instructions for using those functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally managed to do it an other way. Sometimes, you just need to reverse the problem to find a new solution! In this case, instead of directly reading the targeted files, I read all files and selected the ones I needed with function       [whitch]